# Can't initialize web driver using Iceweasel

Tags: python, selenium, debian

I'm trying to install Selenium in Debian 6, using Iceweasel. There is no monitor, so I installed `xvfb`. This is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import os

os.environ["DISPLAY"]=":56017"

url = "www.python.com"

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
driver.get(url) 
text = driver.page_source
driver.quit()
```

`driver = webdriver.firefox()` returns this error:

```
WebDriverException: Message: 'Can\'t load the profile. Profile Dir: 
/tmp/tmp8R_yRq Firefox output: Xlib:  extension "RANDR" missing on display ":
56017.0".\n*** e =
[Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80570016 
(NS_ERROR_XPC_GS_RETURNED_FAILURE) [nsIJSCID.getService]"  nsresult: 
"0x80570016 (NS_ERROR_XPC_GS_RETURNED_FAILURE)"  location: "JS frame :: chrome:
//browser/content/utilityOverlay.js :: getShellService :: line 312"  data: no]
\n'
```

Comment: check if this helps
http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/784936

Answer (score 1):

Which version of Selenium are you using? The newest doesn't work with iceweasel in Debian squeeze. I have been using Selenium with Firefox from:

```
deb http://packages.linuxmint.com debian import
```

It does indeed work with the latest Selenium IDE. I haven't used Selenium with xvfb, but I could test if you tell me version numbers.

NOTE: This is not now answer, but will be when you give me details. I don't have enough rep. to comment, sorry.